# Reading protobuff container using numpy is too slow

Tags: python, numpy, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have implemented a protobuff to send data from a golang client to a python server using a grpc stream. The data I am sending needs to be loaded quickly on the python server and processed. This data is a composite message with the largest field being a repeated int32 array defined as such: `repeated int32 array = 4 [packed=true];`

This field contains around 15,000,000 entries (all of which are between 0 and 100) and when I try to load these into my code using the following line: `data = np.array(array_obj, dtype=np.int8)` this process takes around 1 **SECOND**. I have tried alternative methods of first reading the data as a list, shown here:

```
def read_grpc_container_numpy(array_obj):
    return np.array(array_obj, dtype=np.int8)

def read_grpc_container_list(array_obj):
    return list(array_obj)

def numpy_from_list(list_obj):
    return np.array(list_obj, dtype=np.int8)

def numpy_from_list_iter(list_obj):
    return np.fromiter(list_obj, dtype=np.int8, count=len(list_obj))
```

I could of course leave the object as a python list, but ideally I would like to convert it to a numpy array prior to processing it further. The profiler returns the following information:

```
read_grpc_container_numpy - 1.003s
read_grpc_container_list - 0.446s
numpy_from_list - 0.475s
numpy_from_list_iter - 0.280s
```

Reading as a list and converting to a numpy is faster, but does not grant large gains in terms of performance (1s vs 0.75s).

I would like to try something such as numba or Cython, but both of those would require me to implement the complete container type stored here https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/python/google/protobuf/internal/containers.py . Is there some way this process could be accelerated?

Thankful for any help

Comment: AFAIK protobuf is not really designed with performance in mind. Protobuf does a lot of complex operations for each integer in practice (like bit compaction and many checks). If you care about performance, consider using flatbuffers which should perfectly match with the Numpy strategy. I expect an order of magnitude faster execution for such a case (possibly 2 if the binding is efficient).

Comment: @JérômeRichard It appears the delay is occurring on the line that converts protobuf array to numpy array. It probably lacks any direct C interface specialization for that, causing call to Python code for every element. It would be interesting to test how long `list(array_obj)` takes vs. the numpy conversion from a Python list.

Comment: @jpa I have edited the original question and added comparisons to reading directly as a list. While this is slightly more efficient, it still seems slow (although I guess its fast for python standards), afterwards transforming to a numpy array is actually faster than directly reading as using np.array..

Comment: @JérômeRichard I understand that protobuffs are not optimized for this, but I would have thought that this is quite a common use case, and that some solution exists? I guess fastbuffers are an option, I will see how easy it is to implement, but they would require further changes to compile the code, adapt the docker files etc.

Comment: @deineomaklaut There are some alternative Python protobuf libraries such as [pyrobuf](https://github.com/appnexus/pyrobuf) that may be worth trying, as they claim significantly improved performance. In my experience Google's Python protobuf library is quite slow compared to their C++ library.

Comment: @deineomaklaut https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/main/docs/performance.md should be interesting for you. As you can see the pure-Python version is very slow as indicated by jpa. The "C++-generated-code" version is much faster though it is not fantastic... C++ versions are even faster but I never succeed to reproduce such performance on multiple platforms. I remember having reached few hundred of MiB for repeated arrays. There are ways to optimize the protocol but I did not reach 1 GiB. Flatbuffers succeed to reach few GiB/s on my machine AFAIR.

Comment: @deineomaklaut Note that ProtocolBuffers are mainly focus for network-based interactions initially and so reaching few hundred of MiB (if not a peak of ~1 GiB) was far enough to saturate the network bandwidth of most machines. In fact, 40-120 MiB are often enough for that. In your case, it seems it is 15 MiB which is disappointing indeed. I guess the code generation should fix that (apparently 10x-100x faster).